# Create Package Version Error: Entity Quote not found

Tags: salesforcedx, quote, unlocked-package

I'm trying to create a new unlocked package that adds some custom fields to the Quote object. If I deploy the source to a scratch org everything works as expected.

I created the package running:

```
sfdx force:package:create -n PackageName -d "desc.." -r force-app -t Unlocked -v devHubOrg
```

When I run the following command to the create package version

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p PackageName -d force-app -k "xxxx" -v devHubOrg --wait 10
```

I receive the following Error:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Quote.Opportunity_Owner_Name__c: Entity 'Quote' not found.,Quote.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c: Entity
```

Is there something special I have to do to create a unlocked package that uses the Quote and QuoteLineItem sObjects?

Comment: Does your `sfdx-project.json` file specify a definition file with the `IsQuoteEnabled` org preference enabled?

Comment: @JohnTowers, was in the process of updating my answer to include that after doing a bit more digging on unlocked packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [enable quotes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=quotes_enable.htm).

The [sfdx-project.json](https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#simple-json) file has to [have IsQuoteEnabled set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm).

Comment: Thank you, I added: "definitionFile": "./config/project-scratch-def.json" to the packageDirectories and it seem to have fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

For me it wasn't so obvious. So to save others the time searching:

Config in `./config/project-scratch-def.json` is:

```
"settings": {
    ...
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    }
  }
```